# Unexpected behavior from _StringExplode()

Tags: split, autoit

I have a string: `string1 string2 - string3 string4`. I need it split in two at the `-` (note the space on either side of the "-"). I have the following code which isn't working as expected:

```
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>
#include <String.au3>

Local $test = _StringExplode("string1 string2 - string3 string4", " - ")

MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "Title", $test[1])
```

The output is `string2`. I expected it to be `string3 string4`.

[image]

Must be a small oversight but I'm having trouble finding it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> … explain what I'm doing wrong …

It's [a bug concerning AutoIt v3.3.12.0](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/169792-stringexplode-behavior-after-upgrading-from-33102-to-33120/#comment-1240445) (solved in successive beta). Alternatively [`StringSplit()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/StringSplit.htm) can be used:

```
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>
#include <StringConstants.au3>
#include <Array.au3>

Global Const $g_aTest = StringSplit('string1 string2 - string3 string4', ' - ', $STR_ENTIRESPLIT)

MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, 'Title', $g_aTest[2])
_ArrayDisplay($g_aTest)
```

Including `$STR_NOCOUNT` to `StringSplit()`'s flag parameter returns array identical to `_StringExplode()`.